# R squared weighted by separate variable

Tags: python, linear-regression, weighted

Converting code from STATA to Python and I am trying to figure out how to calculate a regression and R-squared based on STATA's aweight function.

I have my X variable, my Y variable, and want to weight the regression based on a separate Z variable (population). How do you do this in Python?

Answer (score 0):

sklearn aka scikit-learn is my go to library for modelling.
This tutorial might be your answere:
[SGD: Weighted samples](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_sgd_weighted_samples.html)